# Adding derived class object to vector<unique_ptr> of base class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, unique-ptr, derived-class

So in my code I'm trying to add `unique_ptr` to objects from `derived` class to `vector` of base  class. I get this error:

> E0304    no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Organism, std::default_delete<Organism>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Organism, std::default_delete<Organism>>>]" matches the argument list

The code of base class (if you need more let me know, trying to put as little code as possible):

```
vector<unique_ptr<Organism>>  World::generate_organisms(int act_level)
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Organism>> organism_list = get_vector();
    coordinates sheep_pos(10, 2);
    //getting error in next line
    organism_list.push_back(make_unique<Sheep>(sheep_pos, *this));

    return organism_list;
}
```

Code of the derived class:

`.h` file

```
class Sheep : Organism
{
    Sheep( coordinates organism_pos, World* world);
};
```

`.cpp` file

```
Sheep::Sheep( coordinates organism_pos, World* act_world)
    :
    Organism(organism_pos, act_world)
{
    this->armor = 0;
    this->damage = 2;
    this->health = 10;
    this->vigor = 10;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to publicly inherit from Organism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to how the default member visibility of `class` is `private`, inheritance is also `private` unless otherwise specified. You need to inherit from `Organism` `public`ly so that `std::unique_ptr` is able to see and perform the conversions you expect.

```
class Sheep : public Organism {
public:
    Sheep( coordinates organism_pos, World* world);
}
```

Your constructor also needs to be `public` so that `std::make_unique` can see and use it.